# How can I get my express server to redirect the client to a different domain using cors?

Tags: firebase, express, cors, google-cloud-functions

I have an express server that already has cors middlewear enabled.

**https://myapi.com**

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

I have a single page application that makes a request and is suppose to get redirect to paypal after. (It gets served from a different origin as listed below)

**https://myAngularApp.com** (some service)

```
http.post('https://myapi.com/create-payment', data);
```

So back in in the express server, I want to send them off to paypal for authentication:

```
app.post('/create-payment', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/somewhere..');
})
```

Back in the client I get the following error:

> Failed to load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/somewhere: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Looking at the request my client makes to paypal, you can also see that the origin is null.

[image]

---

(Just to note, disabling `app.use(cors({ origin: true }));` won't allow the client to get a normal response from the server, so this already shows that the cors middleware is linked up.

Error when commenting out cors

```
// app.use(cors({ origin: true })); - Commented Out
```

> Failed to load "https://myapi.com/create-payment": Redirect from
>   'https://myapi.com/create-payment' to
>   'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/somewhere.' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'https://myAngularApp.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

---

**What else do I need to setup on the express server so that the client can be redirected to paypal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirects work like this:

1. Client makes HTTP request
2. Server makes HTTP response that includes an instruction to request a different URL
3. Client makes HTTP request to the different URL
4. Server (possibly a different server) makes HTTP response

If, at step 2, the server grants permission to read the response via CORS, then that grants permission for **that** request.

There is no way for the response at step 2 (which is being made by **your** server) to grant permission to read the response at step 4 (which is being made by **PayPal's** server).

If Paypal doesn't grant permission with CORS, then your JavaScript cannot read the response.

(Just imagine if that weren't the case: EvilHacker.Net grants permission with CORS, then redirects to GMail.com, and then EvilHacker can read all your email!)

Comment: Thanks for this, got it to work by doing request client-side :)

Comment: @Jonathan002 i'm facing similar situation. please explain a bit what you did.